# What to do in "Elfenland", if stuck in the desert

Tags: elfenland

There are rare cases in [Elfenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfenland), where it is not possible to move away from a certain place for the whole remaining game. E.g. if you are in the desert city and you have no transportation cards for desert terrain. As you cannot play some cards, they never get exchanged.
It seems not to be described in the manual. What would you do? Exchange the players cards?

Comment: Thank you Erik for adding better tags. I was not able to create these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you playing with the Caravan rules?  From the rulebook:

> If a player cannot play the Travel
>   Card(s) required by the type of
>   transportation, he can play any three
>   Travel Cards (including Raft Travel
>   Cards) instead. This move is called a
>   “Caravan”. “Caravans” only move on
>   roads that provide a type of
>   transportation. Caravans do not travel
>   on rivers and lakes. If there is an
>   Obstacle on the road, the player must
>   play any four instead of three Travel
>   Cards.

As I understand it, Elfenroads did NOT have this rule, making it easier to get stranded.  Apparently some people hate the Caravan rule because it means players don't have to be supremely careful not to get themselves stuck any more...